# Question about inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am reading Sedrakyan's book on inequalities. One of the problems is to prove that:

$\frac{ab}{(a+b)^2}\leq\frac{(1-a)(1-b)}{((1-a)+(1-b))^2}$, where $0<a, b\leq\frac{1}{2}$.

In the proof they say that it is equivalent to proving that

$(\frac{2}{a+b}-1)^2\leq (\frac{1}{a}-1)(\frac{1}{b}-1)$.

I don't understand why this so. And further they say that the above is equivalent to

$\frac{(a-b)^2(1-(a+b))}{ab(a+b)^2}$

which they say is true because $0<a$ and $b\leq \frac{1}{2}$. Why!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the second inequality, if inside each set of parentheses we get a common denominator, we have
$$\frac{(2-a-b)^2}{(a+b)^2}\leq \frac{(1-a)(1-b)}{ab}.$$
Multiplying through by $ab/(2-a-b)^2$ (which is positive because of the restrictions on $a$ and $b$), we get
$$\frac{ab}{(a+b)^2}\leq\frac{(1-a)(1-b)}{(2-a-b)^2},$$
which is the first inequality. The argument works in reverse also.

Now, starting with the second inequality again, if we expand everything out we get
$$\frac{4}{(a+b)^2}-\frac{4}{a+b}+1\leq \frac{1}{ab}-\frac1a - \frac1b + 1.$$
Move everything to the right side and combine all fractions. You end up with the third inequality
$$\frac{(a-b)^2(1-(a+b))}{ab(a+b)^2}\geq 0.$$
Again, the argument works in reverse.

The third inequality holds because of the restrictions on $a$ and $b$. Each factor in the numerator is non-negative and each factor in the denominator is positive.

Comment: But the is that $0<a$ and $b\leq \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Oh--I think you're misunderstanding what $0<a,b\leq 1/2$ means. It means $0<a\leq 1/2$ and $0<b\leq 1/2$.